# How to place the cursor in text box when a page gets loaded by using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am New here for web development  i want to place the cursor on particular text box of website  when page of the website  gets loaded.
i am using the greasemonkey add-ons for it. do u have  any idea how to get the id of the text element from website and how to place the cursor on that text box in javascript.
sourece code of text element is :

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript `focus();`

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("textboxId").focus();
```

**Update:**

If you want to focus on load:

```
...
<script>
      document.getElementById("textboxId").focus();
</script>
//before </body>
</body>
```

Comment: i have one more problem can u help me?

Comment: @Abu If your problem is related to this question you can edit your question, if not go create a new question and we will try to help you.

Comment: this code is works well but problem is targeted text box is too below in a web page and  when page is loaded then cursor is focused on that text box but i still use the mouse to scroll down. i want it automatic so is this possible        my code is:                                          " window.load = a();
function a()
{
  document.getElementById("j_captcha").focus();
} "

Comment: @Abu try `<scirpt>document.getElementById("j_capchat").focus();</script>` put it before `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

In that case using jQuery is ideal, you can focus the textbox by writing this simple code:

```
$('#id').focus();
$('.class').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("someId").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set focus on the text box.

This can be done either by

```
JavaScript document.getElementById("fname").focus();
```

or

```
Jquery $( "#fname" ).focus();
```

or

HTML5

```
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus />
```

Answer (score 0):

if using `Vue.js`

specify a
`ref = "textBoxRef"` on the required element
and use that ref value in the mounted method (similar to on:load in javascript)
to call focus() method on that:

`mounted() {this.$refs.textBoxRef.focus()}`